# setfacl: How to give user permission to a dir for existing and future files?

Tags: linux, permissions, unix, acl

OS: debian:bullseye (docker image).

### What I am trying to do:

I have a websockets server that creates a unix socket and listens on it. I am trying to set up nginx in front of this. I am trying to set up a user `nginx` for nginx, and give it permission to my project root dir (`app`) in a way that `nginx` user will have access to anything already existing (html files) AND anything going to be created (the socket) in this directory.

### What's not working as expected:

I am running this on my project root dir (`app`):
`useradd nginx && setfacl -Rm d:u:nginx:rw,d:g::rw,d:m::rw .`

So, as expected, the defaults are set correctly:

```
root@fa9b4cc3f531:/app# getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:nginx:rw-
default:group::rw-
default:mask::rw-
default:other::r-x
```

and `touch`ing a file also yields the expected permissions:

```
root@fa9b4cc3f531:/app# touch foo
root@fa9b4cc3f531:/app# getfacl foo 
# file: foo
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:nginx:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

#### But

When I am creating an unix socket programatically:

```py
# app/main.py

import websockets
# ...
async with websockets.unix_serve(room.handle_connection, "my-sock.sock"):
    await asyncio.Future()
```

The sock file created has unexpected mask:

```
root@fa9b4cc3f531:/app# getfacl my-sock.sock 
# file: my-sock.sock
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:nginx:rw-                  #effective:r--
group::rw-                      #effective:r--
mask::r--
other::r-x
```

How/why did it compute the `mask::r--`?

Comment: Check the `umask`. I’m not entirely sure how the mask is stored, but the current `umask` value may interfere with it.

Comment: @DanielB umask is `0022`. IIUC, umask governs permissions for new files, but shouldn't have an effect on the mask computed for ACLs. Is that not how it works?

Answer (score 0):

> IIUC, umask governs permissions for new files, but shouldn't have an effect on the mask computed for ACLs

Generally yes, but there are some complications.

Default ACLs indeed override the process-level umask, but **do not** override the "maximum mode" that is specified when creating a file. For example, `open("/app/foo", O_CREAT, 0640)` would normally create a file with `0640 & ~umask` as the resulting mode. When ACLs are involved, it seems that the resulting mode becomes (in this example) `0640 & acl_mode` instead – though I haven't checked the logic in code yet.

So if a program explicitly asks to create a file with 0600 as the maximum mode, neither the umask *nor* the default ACL will add new permissions.

Sockets add another complication. Unlike open(), the bind() call that is used to listen on an address (and which results in the Unix socket "file" being created) does not have a way for the program to specify the desired maximum mode. Therefore `0666 & ~umask` is always being used as the desired mode (as mentioned in the unix(7) manpage) – and that's what gets combined with the default-ACL mode like above, i.e. sockets always become `(0666 & ~umask) & acl_mode`.

Note: I have not yet looked at the kernel source code to verify this logic.

Comment: So, there isn't a way to set ACLs on a dir such that a user will have write access on the sockets that are going to be created?